# Running JUnit TestSuite in command line

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, command-line, junit

So I have been working on this program and I have written the whole thing in java, using Eclipse, and created a test suite for each of my classes.

When I try to run these test files using the normal command line commands, it gives me a whole bunch of errors.

Can someone please tell me how to run your JUnit test suite files using the command line?

Comment: Provide more information, like how you are running your tests, what errors you get, an example of your tests, etc.

Comment: Well to explain the tests I am running, I would have to explain my entire program which would take a long time. The main thing is that all my tests are running just fine on Eclipse. I just don't know how to run JUnit test files from the command line.